# How to print the mysql table's cell name which meet the condition while using OR statement?

Tags: php, mysql

Using 'OR' in mysql query. 
I want to print the cell name of the table by which mean I get the data.

e.g

```
SELECT * FROM routes where stop_1='cityA' OR stop_2='CityA' OR stop_3='CityA' OR stop_1='cityB' OR stop_2='CityB' OR stop_3='CityB'
```

If query runs by `CityA`, I want to know that **cityA**, is which stop? `stop_1`, `stop_2`, `stop_3`?

I want to know `CityA` is `stop_1` or `stop_2` or `stop_3`?

Comment: mysqli_fetch_field()

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_field.asp ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM routes where stop_1='cityA' OR stop_2='CityA' OR stop_3='CityA' OR stop_1='cityB' OR stop_2='CityB' OR stop_3='CityB'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {

    // Get field information for all fields

    while ($fieldinfo = mysqli_fetch_field($result))
        {
        printf("Name: %s\n", $fieldinfo->name);
        printf("Table: %s\n", $fieldinfo->table);
        printf("max. Len: %d\n", $fieldinfo->max_length);
        }

    // Free result set

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Not working I am writing code below please check and give feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You could use case when

```
SELECT 
    case when stop_1='cityA' then 'stop_1' end  check_stop_1_A
  , case when stop_2='cityA' then 'stop_2' end  check_stop_2_A
  , case when stop_3='cityA' then 'stop_3' end  check_stop_3_A
  , case when stop_1='cityB' then 'stop_1' end  check_stop_1_B
  , case when stop_2='cityB' then 'stop_2' end  check_stop_2_B
  , case when stop_3='cityB' then 'stop_3' end  check_stop_3_B     

  FROM routes 
  where stop_1='cityA' 
    OR stop_2='CityA' 
    OR stop_3='CityA'
    OR stop_1='cityB' 
    OR stop_2='CityB' 
    OR stop_3='CityB'
```

Answer (score 0):

**I want to know the stop name?**

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM service WHERE
 stop1='".$dep."' OR stop2='".$dep."' OR stop3='".$dep."' OR stop4='".$dep."' OR stop5='".$dep."' OR stop6='".$dep."' OR stop7='".$dep."' OR stop8='".$dep."' OR stop9='".$dep."' OR stop10='".$dep."' OR stop11='".$dep."' OR stop12='".$dep."' OR stop13='".$dep."' OR stop14='".$dep."' OR stop15='".$dep."' OR stop1='".$des."' OR stop2='".$des."' OR stop3='".$des."' OR stop4='".$des."' OR stop5='".$des."' OR stop6='".$des."' OR stop7='".$des."' OR stop8='".$des."' OR stop9='".$des."' OR stop10='".$des."' OR stop11='".$des."' OR stop12='".$des."' OR stop13='".$des."' OR stop14='".$des."' OR stop15='".$des."' ");